# Error en Assembler NASM para Windows

Tags: windows, ensamblador, compilador, nasm, main

Me estoy iniciando en ensamblador ejecute este código en `nasm` para windows, ejecuta pero no muestra el mensaje "Hola", ¿cómo corregirlo? gracias

```
section .data          
msg "Hola",10          
section .text          
global main            
main:                  
    mov eax,4          
    mov ebx,1          
    mov ecx,msg        
    mov edx,6          
    int 80h            
    
    mov rax,1           
    mov rbx,0           
    int 80h             
   ret
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu código es para Linux 32 bits y por eso no funciona en windows. La version para windows es suficientemente distinta como para considerarla un programa diferente así que no podemos corregirlo.

Busca "hola mundo ensamblador Windows" para ver ejemplos que funcionen en windows.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien el procesador funciona con el mismo conjunto de instrucciones, el código debe adecuarse al sistema operativo.

Tu código no funciona porque es para Linux.

Lo que te concierne usar es la [API de Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/) o la librería estándar. Además debes respetar las [convenciones de Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/calling-conventions?view=msvc-170).

Aquí tienes un ejemplo usando la API de Windows, de [esta pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1029093).

```
    global _main
    extern  _GetStdHandle@4
    extern  _WriteFile@20
    extern  _ExitProcess@4

    section .text
_main:
    ; DWORD  bytes;    
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 4

    ; hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)
    push    -11
    call    _GetStdHandle@4
    mov     ebx, eax    

    ; WriteFile( hstdOut, message, length(message), &bytes, 0);
    push    0
    lea     eax, [ebp-4]
    push    eax
    push    (message_end - message)
    push    message
    push    ebx
    call    _WriteFile@20

    ; ExitProcess(0)
    push    0
    call    _ExitProcess@4

    ; never here
    hlt
message:
    db      'Hello, World', 10
message_end:
```